# How to convert stringArray to function pointer collection for librarySystem

Tags: javascript, arrays, function-pointers, apply

Currently I'm writing a librarySystem

And there's an stringArray ['greet','name'] as dependencies in the code example below, however I need to use this stringArray as an array of functions passing into 
greetingToName()  by using apply(), is there any way to convert the stringArray into An array of functions ?

```
function greet(){
  return 'hi!';
}

function name(){
 return 'name';
}

function greetingToName (greet, name) {
 console.log( greet() + ' ' + name() );
}



var stringArray = ['greet','name'];

greetingToName.apply(null, stringArray); // this is not working properly , because it passes 'greet' and 'name' as string into function, instead of function pointers.
```

Comment: could you describe this mysterious *"function pointer array"*, or add a link to something that documents it's existence?

Comment: Have you tried just removing the quotes, as in `var stringArray = [greet, name];`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3jg7evkw/

Comment: I can't. currently I'm writing an librarySystem, the stringArray will be the dependencies of library.

Comment: @ adeneo,
I think I used the wrong term. can I call it "function pointer collection" ?

Comment: An array of functions would be more correct, but it seems you really want an array of strings, you just want to use those strings to access the functions, and you'd generally do that by putting the functions in an object, and using the strings as keys. The example above uses the global object `window`, but you could use a regular object -> https://jsfiddle.net/3jg7evkw/1/

Comment: this is really an eye opening solution! Just learned something from you !thank you so much for sharing !

but what if I can't expect every function will use the object as its function context ?

Comment: I like adeneos approach to passing property names of object. kudos

Comment: @adeneo
I took your solution as inspiration, then I came up with this.
 -> https://jsfiddle.net/9yqLyo1t/
do you think it's okay ? or it might leads to other problems ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After i've read everybody's solutions here, I got huge inspiration, therefor I came up with this solution without changing the function context , what do you guys think ?

```
var posiableFuncs = {
    greet : function(){
        return 'hi! ';
    },
    name : function(){
        return 'Mr. Awesome!';
    }
}


function greetingToName (greet, name) {
 console.log( greet() + ' ' + name() );
}


var stringArray = ['greet','name'];

// copy the functions and assign into arrayOfFunctions variable based on stringArray
var arrayOfFunctions = stringArray.map(function(functionName){
      return posiableFuncs[functionName];
});

greetingToName.apply(window, arrayOfFunctions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an `Object` with those 2 functions, and pass the strings as you wanted, and then look inside the object by name.

```js
const posiableFuncs = {
  greet: () => {
    return 'hi!';
  },
  name: () => {
    return 'name';
  }
};


function greetingToName(greet, name) {
  console.log(posiableFuncs[greet]() + ' ' + posiableFuncs[name]());
}

const stringArray = ['greet', 'name'];
greetingToName.apply(null, stringArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating function variables and assigning them in array would do the trick.

something as below.

```
var g = function(){
 return 'hi!';
}

var n = function(){
 return 'name';
} 

function greetingToName (greet, name) {
  console.log( greet() + ' ' + name() );
 }



var stringArray = [g,n];
```

Fiddle
 https://jsfiddle.net/dk_dragonknight/yhL188se/